# How to prove that $A-\lambda\,I$ is nilpotent of index smaller than algebraic multiplcity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ by a real $n\times n$ matrix and let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ be one of its eigenvalues with algebraic multiplicity $\mu(\lambda)$. I need to prove that $(A-\lambda\,I)$ ($I$ being the identity matrix) is nilpotent of index $k\leq \mu(A)$. That is, I need to prove that there exists an integer $k\leq \mu(\lambda)$ such $(A-\lambda\,I)^k=0$. I know that it can be proven that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is
$$
p_A(\lambda) = (\lambda-\lambda_1)^{\nu_1}\,\cdots (\lambda-\lambda_q)^{\nu_q}
$$
where $\lambda_j$, $j=1,...,q$, is an eigenvalue of $A$ with algebraic multiplicity $\mu_j\geq\nu_j$. Nevertheless, this result implies that the product
$$
(A-\lambda_1)^{\nu_1}\,\cdots (A-\lambda_q)^{\nu_q}=0
$$
but not that each of the single factors is equal to zero. Probably I am missing some simple and standard results of linear algebra.

Comment: Start with a couple of diagonal matrix examples. They are almost always the easiest to work with.

Comment: The statement is obviously false: take $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$ with $\lambda=1$. Then $A-I$ is definitely not nilpotent.